# Nested list of tuples and list of scores

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a problem, I will try to explain as best as I can.
I have two lists with 3 items each. Each item in list1 has a score in list2.

```
List1= [[(3,4,5)], [(23,44), (23,5,3), (1,2)], [(23,5), (1,6)]]
List2= [2,4,1]
```

As you can see in list1, items 2 and 3 have multiple tuples that correspond to their score, I would like to separate them into their scores:

```
what I want:
List1= [(3,4,5), (23,44), (23,5,3), (1,2), (23,5), (1,6)]
List2= [2,4,4,4,1,1]

or 

List1= [[(3,4,5)], [(23,44)], [(23,5,3)], [(1,2)], [(23,5)], [(1,6)]]
List2= [2,4,4,4,1,1]
```

so far, I have identified the items that needs changing.

```
double = [x for x in List1 if len(x)>1]
print(double)
```

> [[(23, 44), (23, 5, 3), (1, 2)], [(23, 5), (1, 6)]]

I have found the index of these items:

```
indx = [i for y in double for i, x in enumerate(List1) if x== y ]
print(indx)
```

> [1, 2]

I have flattened the nested list to get what I want in list1:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in List1 for item in sublist]
```

> [(3, 4, 5), (23, 44), (23, 5, 3), (1, 2), (23, 5), (1, 6)]

However I am not sure how I can change list2.

any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach (the cryptic one-liner these questions tend to elicit):

```
l1, l2 = zip(*((tpl, scr) for tpls, scr in zip(List1, List2) for tpl in tpls))
l1
# ((3, 4, 5), (23, 44), (23, 5, 3), (1, 2), (23, 5), (1, 6))
l2
# (2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1)
```

The nested generator expression produces the tuple-score pairs, and the `zip(*...)` pattern transposes those into two separate tuples that we capture via multi assignment.
You can easily convert those to lists if you need to.

A more readable and beginner-friendly way:

```
tuples, scores = [], []
for tpls, scr in zip(List1, List2):
    for tpl in tpls:
        tuples.append(tpl)
        scores.append(scr)

tuples
# [(3, 4, 5), (23, 44), (23, 5, 3), (1, 2), (23, 5), (1, 6)]
scores
# [2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1]
```

Comment: A variation of your first one: `l1, l2 = zip(*chain(*map(zip, List1, map(repeat, List2))))`

Comment: Needs some imports, but nice :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use zip to iterate over the items and scores in tandem.

```
List1= [[(3,4,5)], [(23,44), (23,5,3), (1,2)], [(23,5), (1,6)]]
List2= [2,4,1]
new1 = []
new2 = []

# iterate over the list of list of tuples and scores in parallel
for item, score in zip(List1, List2):
    # iterate over the tuples in the list of tuples
    for subitem in item:
        new1.append(subitem)
        new2.append(score)
```

This could be written more succintly as in some of the examples below but for a beginner this is more easily understood.

Comment: `item[0]` is never an `int`. The lone else-block would suffice.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't see that the single value was a list of tuple. I thought some values were tuples and some were lists of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
>>> List1= [[(3,4,5)], [(23,44), (23,5,3), (1,2)], [(23,5), (1,6)]]
>>> List2= [2,4,1]
>>> 
>>> new1 = [w for v in List1 for w in v]
>>> new1
[(3, 4, 5), (23, 44), (23, 5, 3), (1, 2), (23, 5), (1, 6)]
>>> 
>>> new2 = [n for s, n in zip(List1, List2) for i in s]
>>> new2
[2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: `s/ i / _ /` maybe? :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy That is a common convention for unused loop variables.  I didn't bother with it here just to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension:

```
List1Modified = [subset for lists in List1 for subset in lists]
List2Modified = [List2[idx] for idx, lists in enumerate(List1) for _ in lists]

print(List1Modified)
print(List2Modified)

>> [(3, 4, 5), (23, 44), (23, 5, 3), (1, 2), (23, 5), (1, 6)]
>> [2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List1_new=[]
List2_new=[]
for i in range(len(List1)):
    List1_new+=List1[i]
    List2_new+=[List2[i]]*len(List1[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List2 =[List2[j] for j, i in enumerate(List1) for k in range(len(i))]

List1 = [j for i in List1 for j in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hack, building one with list comp and the other as a side effect.

```
l2 = []
l1 = [l2.append(scr) or tpl for tpls, scr in zip(List1, List2) for tpl in tpls]
```

Comment: :-) works and illuminates some Pythonic concepts, but I shall still strangle any junior committing a line like this.

Comment: Not sure whether I'm a junior :-). Might be quite efficient, though. I think I've used that trick to win a performance question a while back.

Comment: Agreed, it's the kind of code that belongs in competitions, but not production code. Not calling you a junior at all, but thinking of the ones in our company :D they'd proudly present this only to be reprimanded.